# Python based quickselect Implementation resulting in error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscripter, quickselect

I have small python code that implements the quickselect discussed [here](http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/QuickSelect).

```
import random
def Quickselect(A, k):
    if not A:
        return
    pivot = random.choice(A)

    i = 0
    A1 = []
    A2 = [] # Two new arrays A1, A2 to store the split lists
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] < pivot :
            A1.append(A[i])
        else:
            A2.append(A[i])

    if k < len(A1):
        return Quickselect(A1, k)
    if k > len(A) - len(A2):
        return Quickselect(A2, k-(len(A) - len(A2)))
    else:
        return pivot
pass
def main():
    A = [45,1,27,56,12,56,88]
    print(Quickselect(A,2))
pass
```

I seem to be getting an randrange error. Is something amiss?

**Edit:** Implemented `random.choice` instead of `random.randint`.
The above code seems to work fine. Thanks to User Blender.

Comment: I added a small check to see if A is empty, I still get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs because `randrange` breaks when the range is empty (i.e. `randrange(1, 1)`).

Use `random.choice` instead and change `k <= len(A1)` to `k < len(A1)`:

```
def quick_select(A, k):
    pivot = random.choice(A)

    A1 = []
    A2 = []

    for i in A:
        if i < pivot:
            A1.append(i)
        elif i > pivot:
            A2.append(i)
        else:
            pass  # Do nothing

    if k <= len(A1):
        return Quickselect(A1, k)
    elif k > len(A) - len(A2):
        return Quickselect(A2, k - (len(A) - len(A2)))
    else:
        return pivot
```

Comment: @AshwinGanesh: `random.choice()` selects a random element from your list. Take a look at how I implemented it in my code.

Comment: @Blender thank you for pointing out the error. My question is: how do you know it's supposed to be `k < len(A1)`? Does that mean the author of the page [http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/QuickSelect.html] got it wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @user1330974: My bad, it should be `<=`.

Comment: @Blender, thanks for the follow-up. But if we try running that with `<=`, we get stackoverflow...

Comment: @user1330974: There was a bug in the original code. You also need to change the `else:` to `elif i > pivot`, as in the webpage.

Comment: @Blender Thank you. :) Didn't realize that adding `elif` and `else` would make the `<=` also work. I don't know how to really trace these recursive algorithms. If you have suggestions on effective way to track/debug them, please let me know. Otherwise, thanks a bunch for the help. :)